# Which package is required to use $\rmint (R)$?

Tags: math-operators, roman

Which package is required to use $\rmint (R)$? could anyone tell me please?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to symbolize the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ by $\int (R)$ that is what I am trying to type.

Comment: @Mico I will edit my question to clarify what I mean by int(R) that I am trying to type.

Comment: your question is hard to understand. have you seen a document somewhere using `\rmint` it is not a command I recognise and you do not show what output you expect.

Comment: no package in the texlive 2020 latex package input tree uses a command `\rmint`

Comment: What is meant by my professor when he said use $\rmint$  is to clarify for us how to write int(R) in latex . the word int here does not mean integral ..... so my question is how to write int(R) in latex ? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Please edit your posting to post a snapshot of a hand-drawn sketch of what you're trying to get typeset.

Comment: `\operatorname{int}(R)` using `amsmath` package

Comment: If you are asking about your teacher's private document macros, why don't you ask your teacher not us!!!

Comment: Is the wikipedia entry [Integral closure of an ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_closure_of_an_ideal) of any use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is impossible to understand but as clarified in comments it appears that you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\rmint{int}

\begin{document}

$\rmint(R)$

\end{document}
```